# Get all specific week days within the range of two date choosers and 7 checkboxes

Tags: java, swing, date, jdatechooser

I have 2 [JDateChooser](https://toedter.com/jcalendar/) controls and 7 `JCheckBox` controls.
The date choosers will set a range between two dates, and the 7 checkboxes will filter the dates.

The 7 checkboxes are:
Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday

**For example:**

- I select Oct 01, 2021, from the first date chooser.
- I select Oct 08, 2021, from the second date chooser.
- I select Monday and Tuesday from the checkboxes.

The output will be all Mondays and Tuesdays in the dates range Oct 01, 2021 - Oct 08, 2021.

I searched everywhere but no answer and I don't even know where to begin.

Comment: checkboxes allow a more distinctive look in the event there are multiple choices to select. and yes I am referring to JDateChooser. If you have a way to do it with radio buttons I'm happy to know that to

Comment: the output will be all the dates in the format "MMM dd, yyyy" to be written in the console.

Comment: [Edit] your question and add that the output will be written to the console. Don't add question details in a comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously schoolwork, so I’ll be brief, enough to point you in the right direction while letting you actually do your own assignment yourself.

Seems obvious that you would use checkbox widgets for the days of the week, not a [combo box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combo_box).

Use `LocalDate` class for the date. Use the `plusDays` method to move from one date to another. Test each using `getDayOfWeek` to match against `DayOfWeek` objects. Use `EnumSet` and its `contains` method for that check.

Use an `ArrayList< LocalDate >` to collect the dates you want to remember.

Make the finished list unmodifiable with a call to `List.copyOf`.

Report the values of the collected `LocalDate` objects by using `DateTimeFormatter`. To automatically localize, use `.ofLocalizedDate`.

---

In advanced Java, we might do something like this untested code.

```
List< LocalDate > dates = 
    LocalDate.of( 2021 , 10 , 1 )
    .datesUntil( LocalDate.of( 2021 , 10 , 8 ) )
    .filter( 
        localDate -> EnumSet.of( DayOfWeek.TUESDAY , DayOfWeek.THURSDAY ).contains( localDate.getDayOfWeek() )
    )
    .toList() 
;
```

Comment: *"Obviously schoolwork.."* This is irrelevant. What's relevant is that questions need to demonstrate a level of research & effort, which this question does not. Plus one for your answer.

Comment: hello Mr.basil I understand your approach and I tried to implement it to my project but the following error pops up.                                                                                   
                                                                                                                               cannot find symbol
                .datesUntil( LocalDate.of( 2021 , 10 , 8 ) )
                ^
  symbol:   method datesUntil(LocalDate)
  location: class LocalDate

Comment: @Thevinu method [datesUntil](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#datesUntil-java.time.LocalDate-) was added to class `java.time.LocalDate` in JDK 9.

Comment: "Obviously schoolwork.." *This is irrelevant.* I beg to differ. There’s a reason why we have got [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: it worked, thank you all for your support.